# What are the potential rift bosses?

Tags: diablo-iii

Last night, while doing some Nephalem rifts, I encountered both "The Butcher" and "Zoltun Kuule" as rift bosses, only they were renamed slightly (The butcher had a different name, and a subtitle of "Meat Chopper"). Both retained several of their boss abilities from their original Acts, but this was the first time I'd encountered former bosses in a rift. Others seemed to be randomly generated champions. Does anyone know, or have enough experience to say, where the rift bosses are picked from?

Comment: what do you mean by "where the rift bosses are picked from"?

Comment: I think he means what pool of characters. So far, EVERY rift guardian I have fought was a boss. I have gotten Rakanoth several times.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a non complete list of rift bosses :

- Agnidox (N/A)
- Bone Warlock (N/A)
- The Binder (N/A)
- Blighter (Herald of Pestilence)
- Bloodmaw (N/A)
- The Choker (N/A)
- Cold Snap (Izual)
- Crusader King (Skeleton King)
- Ember (Nekarat the Keywarden)
- Erethon (Death Maiden)
- Eskandiel (Malthael)
- Flesh Carver (The Butcher)
- Gluttony (Ghom)
- Infernal Maiden (N/A)
- Lord of Bells (Cow King [Easter Egg])
- Mistress of Pain (Cydaea)
- Perdition (Rakanoth)
- Perendi (Mallet Lord)
- Raiziel (N/A)
- Reformed Warden (Warden)
- Rime (Xahrith the Keywarden)
- Rokrak (Fallen Champion)
- Stone Singer (Sand Golem)
- Sand Shaper (Zoltun Kulle)
- Satrix (Writhing Deceiver)
- Spider Queen (Queen Araneae)
- Tethrys (Succubus)
- Voracity (N/A)

I'll complete and cross check it later with data from achievements.

Comment: There's one called Choker that I hate because of her insane poison damage... she's the only one I ever remember though.

Comment: Raiziel is one also